# Blazor navigation without reload

Tags: navigation, blazor

Below is the razor component which is the navigation menu.  Everything loads great and I'm able to login with no problem.  The problem is, after login, I navigate to the home page and  the @IsLoggedOn() doesn't execute, unless I force a reload, which I'm trying to avoid.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <nav class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Home</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler @NavButtonCssClass" type="button" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse @NavBarCssClass" id="navbarCollapse" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Login">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Login
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <nav IsList="true" Alignment="Alignment.Right" IsNavbar="true">
            @if (isLoggedOn())
            {
                <NavLink href="/Logout">
                    Logout
                    <span class="oi oi-lock-unlocked" title="lock unlocked" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </NavLink>
            }
            else
            {
                <NavLink href="Login">
                    Login
                    <span class="oi oi-lock-locked" title="lock locked" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </NavLink>
            }
        </nav>
    </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged());` to notify blazor that a component has changed. It wont rerender the whole page, only the changed component.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I tried your suggestion in the OnInitialized of the form I'm navigating to, after login.

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
However, it doesn't appear to work.  Is there another place I should call this from?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the NavMenu has no mechanism of recognising  authentication state changes - the logged in Identity has changed.

You can do this by injecting the `AuthenticationStateProvider` and then hooking up an event handler (that calls `StateHasChanged`) to the `AuthenticationStateProvider`'s `AuthenticationStateChanged` event.

This should work.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

..... Razor

    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider? AuthState { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // other code you may have
        AuthState.AuthenticationStateChanged += this.OnAuthStateChanged;
    }

    private async void OnAuthStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> state)
        => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => AuthState.AuthenticationStateChanged -= this.OnAuthStateChanged;
```

Comment: My Blazor app is a WebAssembly which talks to a Web API server and uses JWT for authentication.  In my nav menu, I was simply trying to get the Login to change to Logout, once the user is logged in.  Whatever I tried, didn't seem to work.   I came up with one solution which works but one I'm not happy with at all.  In the OnInitalized event of the nav menu, I start a background thread which calls StateHasChanged() every 15 seconds.    It works but until I find a better solution, not sure what else to do.

Comment: So which `AuthenticationStateProvider` are you using?  How do you set it up?

Comment: I'm using a project I use with a WPF desktop app.  It's a group of classes which make HttpClient calls to the Web API server.  One of the classes is used for authentication which gets a token.  The token is stored locally and used for subsequent calls.

Comment: You don't need to do the timer.  The NavMenu update can be driven by an event from your log in process.  What does `IsLoggedIn` call to check if the user is logged in?

Comment: As I said, I wasn't happy with the timer solution at all.  I knew there had to be an event driven solution I just hadn't figured it out yet.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: NP.  @Enet beat me to the draw and gave you a very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the methods mentioned above, but none of them worked. I don't know why. I found a solution on [this website](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/force-reload-blazor-component/), which is to use "forceLoad" argument in NavigateTo function to forcefully refresh the webpage. Hope it helps.